# Krajee bootstrap fileinput-Showing image from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using [Krajee bootstrap fileinput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-advanced-usage-demo) plugin for image upload during Employee registration process.Image is saved to a folder in the project and the path is saved into the database.

While editing the employee I want to show the uploaded image from the database.

My question is how can I show the image from the database.

**Db structure is**

```
EmployeeId        PhotoUrl

   1             ~/UploadImages/Employee/Photo/Emp1.jpg
```

I have got the sample code from the website

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
$("#input-24").fileinput({
    initialPreview: [
        '<img src="/images/moon.jpg" class="file-preview-image" alt="The Moon" title="The Moon">',
        '<img src="/images/earth.jpg" class="file-preview-image" alt="The Earth" title="The Earth">'
    ],
    overwriteInitial: false,
    maxFileSize: 100,
    initialCaption: "The Moon and the Earth"
});
```

});

How can i get `intialPreview` from the database ?

**HTML markup**

```
<div class=" form-group ">
  <label for="txtPhoto" class=" control-label">
    Photo
  </label>
  <label class="reqdLabel">
    *
  </label>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhotoUrl, new { @class = "form-control imgUpload", @placeholder = "Please upload Photo", @id = "txtPhoto", @type = "file" }) 

  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhotoUrl)

</div>
```

**JQuery for calling fileInput**

```
//fileUpload plugin
$(".imgUpload").fileinput({
    showUpload: false,
   //How can I set value here
    initialPreview: [
        '<img src="~/UploadImages/Employee/AddressProof/Emp16.jpg" class="file-preview-image" alt="The Moon" title="The Moon">'           
    ],
    overwriteInitial: false,
    initialCaption: "Emp16.jpg"
});
```

Comment: Do you have a model/view model for the employee? It should contain a property say `IEnumerable<string> PhotoUrl` for the collection of url's so that you can assign them in the view.

Comment: Okay I understood that.I have to create a seperate `image tag` in the view and set the `src` to `PhotoUrl`. Is it possible to show the image the above mentioned fileinput itself?

Comment: Can an employee have multiple images (or just one)?

Comment: Oops forget to say `thanks for your attention`:).Only one image is possible for an employee.

Comment: In that case, you would probably just need `initialPreview: [ '<img src="@Model.PhotoUrl" class="file-preview-image" ... >' ]` assuming you model has a property `string PhotoUrl`

Comment: I have edited the question included HTML and Jquery version.How can I set `@Model.PhotoUrl` in jquery?

Comment: Why do you need to? What wrong with the code in my last comment? - `'<img src="@Model.PhotoUrl" ... >'` But `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhotoUrl, ..)` does not make sense. That suggests property `PhotoUrl` is typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` but its a `string` I think you need 2 properties, one for the image url, and one for the file upload.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input mate. I think I will have two seperate sections in the  case of editing an employee, one of `image viewing` and another for `uploading the image`.In the `image view section` I will set the initial preview as mentioned by you and in the `image upload section` I will set textbox type to `HttpPostedFileBase`

Comment: It would be best to have a view model with 2 properties `string PhotoUrl` and `HttpPostedFileBase PhotoFile` and then in the view you can have `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhotoFile, new { type = "file", @class = "imgUpload" })` and use the script as per above comments so you can have both (existing image display and a file upload to replace the file)

Comment: Yup..Thanks `Super Steve` for your valuable input. If you could post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign the initial image, you can use

```
$(".imgUpload").fileinput({
  showUpload: false,
  initialPreview: [
    '<img src="@Model.PhotoUrl" class="file-preview-image" .... >'           
  ],
  ....
});
```

However you use of `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhotoUrl, ...)` will not work because `type="file"` posts back to typeof `HttpPostedFileBase` but property `PhotoUrl` is typeof `string`.

You could manually generate the html

```
<input type="file", name="photoFile" class="imgUpload" ... />
```

and then the POST method would include a parameter for the uploaded file

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee model, HttpPostedFileBase photoFile)
```

or better, use a view model that contains properties for the url and the file

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
  public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
  public HttpPostedFileBase PhotoFile { get; set; }
  .... // other properties
}
```

and in the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhotoFile, new { type = "file", @class = "imgUpload" })
```